# Any way to create a Object that extends Array?

Tags: javascript

I have created a lexer in javascript, and where im now using an array to describe a range of items, i now see the use of having my own Range object so i can properly distinguish an "array" and a "range array" in such a way that it reads nicely.

So is there any way i can create a hugely cross browser compatible sublcass of the Array object?

Or would a better/simpler approach just using array as is, and for "range arrays" i just tag the array with a property of my own choosing?

something like:

```
var myRange = [1,2,3];
myrange.isRangeObj = true;

//i would then use if(myRange.isRangeObj) to do specific range operations.
//However i still think myRange instanceof Range reads better
```

Comment: Why do you need to check that at all? You shouldn't have a non-rangy value in the `myRange` variable.

Comment: `if (typeof myRange=='object')` perhaps ?

Comment: Yes but i don't have any custom logic, i just want to distinguish a range array and a normal array, later there will be other different array types. Mainly i want to be able to use the same functions as present in the Array object, and also be able to distinguish it as an object of type Range

Comment: No. Read [how ECMAScript 5 still does not allow to subclass an array](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Array.prototype.isRangeObj = false;
```

So all the arrays created by you will have the property `isRangeObj`

Comment: do i need to add it to prototype? would it not suffice to add it to a single instance of array? `var arr = []; arr.isRangeObj = false`. That way i dont mess with the global scope of array.

Comment: Well, I don't really need add it to prototype, it's like you said, I can add only to a single instance, but other instances of `Array` will return `undefined` for `isRangeObj`, so depends of the case, if `undefined` is enough, so it's better add it to a single instance.

Answer (score 1):

Use composition in javascript to create an Object that extends Array:

```
function Range(arr) {
  this.arr = arr;
}

var myRange = new Range([1, 2, 3]);

if (myRange instanceof Range) {
    doSomethingWithRange(myRange.arr);
}
```

Comment: I guess that is one solution.